# Jitterbit local file import failing

Tags: jitterbit

I am trying setup a local json file as a source in Jitterbit. I am getting an error saying:

EnableLocalFileLocation=true

is required in the jitterbit.conf file to test the source.

This is setup however and the server has been restarted and I'm still getting the error.

The full error is :

*Using local files as source/target, trigger file or success/error folders are disabled by default.
Set EnableLocalFileLocation=true in the [Settings] section of 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jitterbit Agent\jitterbit.conf' and restart the Jitterbit Apache service to enable it.
Studio version: 8.26.1.3
Studio platform: Windows 10 - Java 1.8.0_121*

Any ideas?
Thanks Martin

Comment: I'm getting errors trying to connect to a local SQL server db and a remove SQL server db.

The error in this case is : 

*Failed to connect to database. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (SqlState: 08001).
Studio version: 8.26.1.3
Studio platform: Windows 10 - Java 1.8.0_121*

As far as I can see my connection parameters were correct in both cases. The server name for the local db was the server name I use in SQL server manager which works fine. And the remote db I used the IP address which also works fine in SQL server manager.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you are working with local files, you are working with files that are on your same server as the local agent?  You are not trying to use JitterBit's cloud agent?

Comment: yes, same server

Comment: @W3BGUY yes - issue was due to using the cloud agent. Errors didn't indicate this but Jitterbit support confirmed it. Thanks for your feedback. If you want to give as answer I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the cloud agent: Just to be sure, when you are working with local files, you are working with files that are on your same server as the local agent? You are not trying to use JitterBit's cloud agent?